# How to customize Windows 7 Explorer navigation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I would like to customize the left side of my windows explorer. Can someone point me to a tutorial how to do this or maybe even give me a solution?

I would like to change it from left (how it looks like right now) to the way it looks on the right side.

[image]

I have found a few QA's on this page how to remove this or that, but I want to customize it how I like, not only remove something.
There also seems to be [a tool available](http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-navigation-pane-customizer-show-hide-rename-items-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane/) but it looks like that it only permits to hide/show navigation entries but not to re-order them.

Comment: only to show people what are you saying about removing favorites: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-favorites-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/